# How to structure a 'select' FQL statement in javascript

Tags: javascript, faunadb

I have a Fauna database with a collection "rooms" and an index "all_rooms_by_name"

I can run the query

```
Map(
    Paginate(Match(Index("all_rooms_by_name"), "57|65")),
    Lambda("roomRef", Get(Var("roomRef")))
)
```

in the Fauna shell and I get the expected response

```
[
{
    data: [Collection("rooms")]
},
{
    data: [
    Index("all_rooms_by_name")
    ]
},
{
    data: [
    {
        ref: Ref(Collection("rooms"), "336166823854604873"),
        ts: 1656852515940000,
        data: {
        name: "57|65",
        users: {}
        }
    }
    ]
}
]
```

I am trying to emulate this in javascript using the [Fauna docs](https://docs.fauna.com/fauna/current/drivers/javascript?lang=javascript#pagination-helpers)

```
const faunadb = require("faunadb");
const query = faunadb.query;
const client = new faunadb.Client({
    secret: process.env.FAUNA_SECRET
});

var query_function = client.paginate(
    query.Match(
        query.Index('all_rooms_by_name'),
        '57|65'
    )
)


var response = await client.query(query_function)
```

But it returns an error and response contains {}. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

The problem lay in the structure of the *query_function*. Guided by [this thread](https://forums.fauna.com/t/how-to-update-a-document-in-fauna-without-knowing-the-ref-id/3140/2) I changed it to

```
query_function = query.Map(
    query.Paginate(query.Match(query.Index(all_rooms_by_name), key)),
    (recordRef) => query.Get(recordRef)
);
```

And it returns a list of records